# How to define a variable from an imported function in Python?

Tags: variables, import, undefined

Python 3.10.11

So let's say i have 2 files:

test1.py
test2.py

In test1.py I have a function and a constant variable:

```
Z = 50

def func():
   x = 100
   return x
```

In test2.py I import the function(s) from test1.py, call it, and want to use the variable it created:

```
from test1 import *

func()
y = Z + x
print(y)
```

(Z) is defined but not (x), how can I make (x) defined in test2.py?

I assume the problem is that (x) isn't created until I call the function, since it isn't created it can't be imported together with (Z) and func().

I have tried to write global in a few places, having very little hope that it would work, which of course it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Heres what to do: (I haven't tried python in a while, so im sorry if this doesn't work)
in test1.py, change x like this:

```
z = 50
func():
    global x 
    x = 100
    return x
```

Comment: This should turn x into a global variable, meaning it can be used anywhere